# Jquery multiple lists of products dropdown

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I need help with jquery to select multiple options from Jquery dropdown.
I currently can select single value from option list with jquery. But I need to be able to select a list of items on option selection. For example in below example I can select values fine. But I also have products for each country in select options. How can I display products per country with a selectbox upon user's selection. Idea is for user to get number of products displayed in dropdown and upon selection of country it will display number of products exists for the country on click. Image is attached for more clarification.

Countries:

```
<select id='selectCountry'>
<option selected='selected' value='USA">United States</option> # I need to include all the products related to this country here
<option value='PK'>Pakistan</option>
<option value='UK'>United Kingdom</option>
<option value='CA'>Canada</option>
</select>
```

Script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#selectCountries').change(function(){
var selectOption = $("#selectCountries option:selected');
$('#divResult').html('Value = ' + selectOption.val()
+ ', Text + selectOption.text());
});
});
<script>
})
```

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think u can use multi-select dropdown , please check this link. it may helpful to you  :  [click here](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget)

Comment: This much I can do Priya but what further I need to do is to show a list of items in "Foo" or "bar" or "baz". So each option should present a list of items.